# How to retrieve showcase status updates through company page API in LinkedIn

Tags: rest, api, linkedin-api

I have the following REST call to get the status updates of a company page:

```
GET https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/<id>/updates?event-type=status-update&count=20&format=json
```

The company now has a showcase page and wants me to get the *status-updates* of this page, too. The problem is that I do not have and page id for this showcase page.

They tell me the showcase page is a child of the original page and the api should be able to show their *status-updates* as well.

Any idea how to get those? I only get the original company updates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be possible with LinkedIn v2 API, though I didn't try it. Furthermore it seems you have to apply as a LinkedIn partner to use v2 API.

> ## Find Organization Brands by Parent Organization
>
> Members with access to this API can look up the basic information of
>   an organization using the parent organization URN. This returns an
>   array of brands that belong to the specified parent organization.
>
> **Sample Request**
>
> GET https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizations?q=parentOrganization&parent=[organization_URN]

See:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/organizations/organization-lookup-api#find-organization-brands-by-parent-organization